# Using argument expansion {*} with more than one statement

Tags: tcl, eval, variable-expansion

I am using `{*}` in tcl for argument expansion and come across this issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh

set reset {
        set count 0;
        set age 24;
}

puts $reset

eval $reset; # This is working fine. Commented out the below line and tried

{*}$reset; # This is throwing error. Commented out the above line and tried.

if { [ info exists count ] && [ info exists age ] } {
        puts "count & age initialzed to  $count and $age"
} else {
        puts "count & age not initialzed :("
}
```

As you see, I have the reset variable defined and I am evaluating with `eval` as well as with `{*}`.

While `eval` is working fine, `{*}` is throwing error as

```
wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
    while executing
"{*}$reset"
```

Then I have changed the variable `reset` as follows,

```
set reset {
            set count 0;
    }
```

i.e. I have removed the 2nd `set` statement and the code works fine.

Why `{*}` is working fine with one statement and not with more than that ? Or What I am missing here ?

Comment: Erm, even with the single command, it doesn't 'work' as such because `$count` will have the value `0;` instead of `0`, which actually explains the problem: the `;` is being interpreted as a string and not as a meta-character for the code.

Comment: Yes. Jerry. You are right. Now only I am also observing that. Then at one instance, one command alone can be used ?

Comment: I wouldn't advise using the argument expansion like that because I don't think that's the reason why `{*}` was implemented. To evaluate code, use `eval` and to expand a list, use `{*}`.

Comment: With two lines, it is like you are evaluating `set count "0;" set age "24;"`.

Comment: Since `reset` really contains a script, `eval` is exactly the right thing to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commands lite `eval` and `uplevel` (and `while` and `if` etc) can evaluate scripts, i.e. strings/lists that consist of zero or more command invocations. When you invoke `{*}$reset` you get six words instead of one, but the interpreter still expects a single command invocation. What actually gets invoked is the command `set` with five arguments, and the command will balk at that.

Expanding a word into several words works as long as the expansion forms exactly one command invocation:

```
set foo bar
# => bar
```

Too few words:

```
set cmd set
# => set
{*}$cmd
# => wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

Too many words:

```
set cmd {set foo baz ; set abc def}
# => set foo baz ; set abc def
{*}$cmd
# => wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
```

Just right:

```
set cmd {set foo}
# => set foo
{*}$cmd
# => bar
set cmd {set foo baz}
# => set foo baz
{*}$cmd
# => baz
```

Also just right:

```
set cmd set
# => set
{*}$cmd ghi jkl
# => jkl
set cmd {set mno}
# => set mno
{*}$cmd pqr
# => pqr
```

Documentation: [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm), [uplevel](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/uplevel.htm), [while](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/while.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Hoodiecrow. :)